# Shift function so it passes through a specific point.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I have a function that rappresents the average of a series of points.
This function is an approximation and once I have this, I need to shift it so it passes through a single given point.

So basically, take the given function, and shift it horizontally and vertically so it passes through a point.

the function is: `y = b0+(b1*x)`
where b0 = 1864, b1=-1.93, x=610

the point the function must pass through is: 558/778

Could you please explain how the above function needs to be edited in order to pass through the given point?

Comment: Do you want it to pass through the point $(558,778)$, or do you mean the point $(610, \frac{558}{778})$?

Comment: @M.Nestor the point is x=558 Y=778. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be any function and $(x_0,y_0)$ be any point in $\mathbb R^2$. The function $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by
$$
g(x) = f(x-x_0)+y_0-f(0)
$$
has as its graph the graph of $f$ where the point $(0, f(0))$ is shifted to $(x_0, y_0)$.

When $f(x) = b_0+b_1 x$, this yields
$$
g(x) = b_1(x-x_0)+y_0.
$$